# JBoss can not startup because of port in use

Tags: jboss

All, I am not familiar with the JBoss, recently I was working with it because of job, now I am stuck with a problem when I start up the JBoss. After searching the answer in the google , I didn't found anything helpful, Hope you can help me to review it . thanks.

The main exception of JBoss start up said.

```
13:30:07,653 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.7.0_05,Oracle Corporation
13:30:07,653 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 23.1-b03,Oracle Corporation
13:30:07,654 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,x86
13:30:10,515 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
13:30:19,756 INFO  [EncryptedSystemPropertiesService] Loaded system properties from: file:/D:/AA7.2.0/av.7.2.0/av.biz/conf/av/ServerConfig.properties
13:30:19,778 INFO  [EncryptedSystemPropertiesService] Loaded system properties from: file:/D:/AA7.2.0/av.7.2.0/av.biz/conf/av/system.properties
13:30:21,692 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://joe-wang.achievo.com:3083/
13:30:21,693 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
13:30:22,666 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=WebService
 java.lang.Exception: Port 3083 already in use.
      at org.jboss.web.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:233)
      at org.jboss.web.WebService.startService(WebService.java:322)
      at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
```

Firstyly I thought there is some process already use the port 3083. So I use the dos command to show all the port status .

```
netstat -a
```

The below is all the port list .

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:21             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:82             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:902            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:912            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1045           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1054           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1316           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1322           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2074           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2137           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2138           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2140           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2382           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8787           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8890           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8898           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8988           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:9089           joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:54321          joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:56789          joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    10.50.70.133:139       joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    10.50.70.133:445       ACA-SERVER:45627       ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:1411      cs109p1:5050           ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:1450      sip105p2:5050          ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:1461      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2265      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2274      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2302      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2327      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2333      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2343      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2345      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2349      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2397      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2454      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2455      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2456      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2457      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2458      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2459      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2460      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2461      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2462      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2463      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2465      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2466      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2467      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2468      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2469      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2470      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2471      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2472      tmg01:8080             ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2495      sitesz:epmap           TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2496      sitesz:1025            ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.50.70.133:2498      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2499      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2500      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2501      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2502      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2503      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2504      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2505      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    10.50.70.133:2506      tmg01:8080             TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:1355         joe-wang:1356          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1356         joe-wang:1355          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1405         joe-wang:1406          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1406         joe-wang:1405          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1448         joe-wang:1449          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1449         joe-wang:1448          ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:1777         joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:1777         joe-wang:31000         ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:2075         joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:8307         joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:12001        joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:31000        joe-wang:1777          ESTABLISHED
TCP    192.168.98.1:139       joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    192.168.198.1:139      joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:21                joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:80                joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:82                joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:135               joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:443               joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:445               joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1025              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1026              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1027              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1045              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1316              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1322              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2074              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2137              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2138              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2140              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2382              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:3389              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8890              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8898              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8988              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:9089              joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:54321             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::]:56789             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:2075             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:8307             joe-wang:0             LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:12001            joe-wang:0             LISTENING
UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:1434           *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:3600           *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:54847          *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:56477          *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:57586          *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:64553          *:*
UDP    10.50.70.133:137       *:*
UDP    10.50.70.133:138       *:*
UDP    10.50.70.133:1900      *:*
UDP    10.50.70.133:55282     *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:49890        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:50195        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:50469        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:52636        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:54848        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:55285        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:56474        *:*
UDP    127.0.0.1:62117        *:*
UDP    192.168.98.1:137       *:*
UDP    192.168.98.1:138       *:*
UDP    192.168.98.1:1900      *:*
UDP    192.168.98.1:55283     *:*
UDP    192.168.198.1:137      *:*
UDP    192.168.198.1:138      *:*
UDP    192.168.198.1:1900     *:*
UDP    192.168.198.1:55284    *:*
UDP    [::]:123               *:*
UDP    [::]:500               *:*
UDP    [::]:1434              *:*
UDP    [::]:4500              *:*
UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
UDP    [::1]:55281            *:*
UDP    [fe80::35f5:46d0:818f:3594%16]:1900  *:*
UDP    [fe80::35f5:46d0:818f:3594%16]:55280  *:*
UDP    [fe80::b01e:59e5:ee84:87f9%11]:1900  *:*
UDP    [fe80::b01e:59e5:ee84:87f9%11]:55278  *:*
UDP    [fe80::b4e4:39b:b59a:9463%14]:1900  *:*
UDP    [fe80::b4e4:39b:b59a:9463%14]:55279  *:*
```

But I found the 3083 is not in the port list above . Could anyone tell me why? Did I missed something? Thanks for you kindly help.

Comment: have you checked if your jboss startup configuration uses the same port for two different services

Comment: Hi, eis, I just started up only one JBoss. thanks.

Comment: I'm talking about services here, not JBoss instances :) One instance of JBoss has multiple services, like manage-native in port 9999, http admin at 9990, management-https at 9443, ajp 8009, http 8080, https 8443, remoting 4447, txn-recovery at port 4712... check your JBoss configuration if there's anything overlapping.

Comment: I see.Let me check it. I will post it when necessary.thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what environment you are running, hard to say what it is. Here is explanation for Windows:

Port Number: 3083 (Windows 7/Windows Vista/ Windows XP/Windows Server family)
TL1 Telnet--
Protocol Used : tcp/udp 
Service Type : tl1-telnet 
Known Port 3083 exploits: Yes 
Known Port 3083 Security Risks: Yes

Comment: Hi , Mike , Thanks your help, Finally I got what's the really problem. My computer's IP is assigned by DHCP server automatically. Recently it has been changed silently(I don't know why). so the previous IP value in jboss setting is actually not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Change port Number.
Run the eclipse click on server and change
[image]1.